# Has any scientist elaborated on the "selfish neuron" hypothesis?

Tags: neuroscience

[Daniel Dennett references a talk by Sebastian Seung](https://www.edge.org/response-detail/10446), where the latter speaks about "selfish neurons". I've been trying to learn more about this hypothesis, but cannot seem to find anyone who has elaborated on this line of thinking. Could someone point me to some resources, or this an idea whose time has not yet come?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the "selfish neurons" idea is a lot less interesting in terms of biological implications than the similarly-named "selfish gene" hypothesis.

It's basically proposing a bottom-up understanding of neuronal circuits where the developmental design feature is that neurons are individually optimizing their input-output relationships in some way. There isn't really any biological controversy about this suggestion.

Dennett (and probably others) goes a little crazy with it and turns it into a discussion of the agency of individual neurons, etc, but from a biological perspective I would argue that this is a pretty boring type of agency, at least in so far as using this definition pretty much all cells in a biological organism would be argued to have agency, because they are on some level "making decisions," but that's all biology is: organic systems of machines that respond in some way to their environment, and which are subject to selection pressures by which the systems of machines that reproduce best come to predominate.

Where this argument *is* useful, and Dennett uses this approach as well, is in contrasting biological systems with silicon computers. However, all of today's machine learning algorithms are really based on "selfish" nodes according to Dennett's description.

**In summary,** the selfish neuron hypothesis is just a philosophical approach to what we already know about biological neurons. It's meant as a way especially for people from a more algorithmic/computational background to think about how biological neural networks differ from algorithms structured from logical first principles. It doesn't make strong hypotheses for biology *beyond what is already understood and agreed upon.* I think this is probably why you don't see much more study about it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94372/discussion-on-answer-by-bryan-krause-has-any-scientist-elaborated-on-the-selfis).